# casting UTC unixtime to timestamp in the same timezone

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I want to convert an epoc field into a UTC timestamp and I am using the code below.

```
df.withColumn(
  TargetColumn,
  to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col(SourceColumn) / 1000), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

A sample value for the SourceColumn is `1580452395095L` which should yield `2020-01-31 06:33:15.0`
however when I try this code it gives `2020-01-31 07:33:15.0`

Seems like to_timestamp function uses the local timezone of the system, I even tried to set spark timezone as

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```

But this also didn't work, is there a way to make this code always convert to a UTC timestamp regardless of the environment it runs on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the timezone in config should fix the issue. Actually setting up `"spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC"` anywhere in config should work.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("test")
    .master("local")
    .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC").getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (1580452395095L)
).toDF("DATE")

df.withColumn("NEW_DATE",
  to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("DATE") / 1000), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
    .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|DATE         |NEW_DATE           |
+-------------+-------------------+
|1580452395095|2020-01-31 06:33:15|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Without setting the timeZone, we get

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|DATE         |NEW_DATE           |
+-------------+-------------------+
|1580452395095|2020-01-31 07:33:15|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable it only for a specific dataframe operation irrespective of how the spark session is created, then this should help.

Default would be

```
java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault

res50: java.time.ZoneId = Asia/Calcutta
```

The same would reflect when you query the spark configuration.

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.session.timeZone").show(false)

+--------------------------+-------------+
|key                       |value        |
+--------------------------+-------------+
|spark.sql.session.timeZone|Asia/Calcutta|
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Now the dataframe

```
val df = Seq((1580452395095L)).toDF("DATE")
```

Change it to UTC - London

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone","Europe/London")
```

Querying the config settings would show London

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.session.timeZone").show(false)

+--------------------------+-------------+
|key                       |value        |
+--------------------------+-------------+
|spark.sql.session.timeZone|Europe/London|
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Result:

```
df.withColumn("NEW_DATE", to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("DATE") / 1000))).show(false)

+-------------+-------------------+
|DATE         |NEW_DATE           |
+-------------+-------------------+
|1580452395095|2020-01-31 06:33:15|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Changing it back to system default,

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone",java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault.toString)

df.withColumn("NEW_DATE", to_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("DATE") / 1000))).show(false)

+-------------+-------------------+
|DATE         |NEW_DATE           |
+-------------+-------------------+
|1580452395095|2020-01-31 12:03:15|
+-------------+-------------------+

spark.sql("SET spark.sql.session.timeZone").show(false)

+--------------------------+-------------+
|key                       |value        |
+--------------------------+-------------+
|spark.sql.session.timeZone|Asia/Calcutta|
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try appending the following line in your `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` file:

```
spark.sql.session.timeZone UTC
```

If necessary you can also set the JVM timezones using:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Duser.timezone=GMT
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Duser.timezone=GMT
```